# Phrase for "It's good so that it helps my practice too"

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, synonyms

I'm looking for a phrase that gives the meaning of something like, "Glad you asked me that, (I had forgotten that) so that I can practice it".
Like, when your friend is also from your country and neither of you speaks English natively, but I tell him that "well it's good that we are talking in English, that way I can make my English better too"
I've so far heard something like, "It is good to learn the ropes", from a guy on facebook, (he is also from my place) but I didn't came up with relevant results for that in Google..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Term for a type of relationship that two parties benefit from](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462947/term-for-a-type-of-relationship-that-two-parties-benefit-from) ('mutually beneficial'; 'win-win' ...')

Answer (score 1):

"win-win" is a possible candidate, meaning:

Beneficial or satisfactory to all parties involved.

So, you could say to you friend:

"It's good that you are talking in English;  this way I can better my English-speaking skills too". It's a win-win deal.

Comment: Does it give the meaning of, "It's good for my practice too (You speaking with me in English)"?

Comment: *Does it give the meaning of, "It's good for my practice too... ?* -Yes